# Running GCC precompiler on Java code

Tags: java, gcc

I'm trying to run the GCC precompiler on Java code by issuing the following command: "gcc -D YES -E -x c -o YesNo.java _YesNo.java". The gcc precompiler adds some extra stuff/info in the beginning of the file, though, as can be seen below. How do I instruct the precompiler not to create such outputs so I can compile the output of the precompiler directly without making any modifications? Thanks in advance!

Java input to GCC:

```
 public class YesNo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        #ifdef YES
            System.out.println("YES");
        #else
            System.out.println("NO");
        #endif
    }
}
```

GCC precompiler output:

```
 # 1 "Slask.pjava"
 # 1 "<built-in>"
 # 1 "<command line>"
 # 1 "Slask.pjava"

 public class YesNo
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

             System.out.println("YES");



    }
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You just need the `-P` arg.

You might also want to run the `cpp` command, rather than `gcc`.

Finally, note the following FSF caution from `man cpp`:

> The C preprocessor is intended to be
>   used only with C, C++, and Objective-C
>   source code.  In the past, it has been
>   abused as a general text processor. 
>   It will choke on input which does not
>   obey C’s lexical rules.  For example,
>   apostrophes will be interpreted as the
>   beginning of character constants, and
>   cause errors.  Also, you cannot rely
>   on it preserving characteristics of
>   the input which are not significant to
>   C-family languages.  If a Makefile is
>   preprocessed, all the hard tabs will
>   be removed, and the Makefile will not
>   work.
>
> Having said that, you can often get
>   away with using cpp on things which
>   are not C.  Other Algol-ish
>   programming languages are often safe
>   (Pascal, Ada, etc.) So is assembly,
>   with caution.  -traditional-cpp mode
>   preserves more white space, and is
>   otherwise more permissive. Many of the
>   problems can be avoided by writing C
>   or C++ style comments instead of
>   native language comments, and keeping
>   macros simple.
>
> Wherever possible, you should use a
>   preprocessor geared to the language
>   you are writing in.  Modern versions
>   of the GNU assembler have macro
>   facilities.  Most high level
>   programming languages have their own
>   conditional compilation and inclusion
>   mechanism.  If all else fails, try a
>   true general text processor, such as
>   GNU M4.

Note the reference to `m4(1)`. I suspect `cpp` will work fine on Java, but if it doesn't just use `m4`.

Answer (score 1):

Preprocessing will (in my opinion) make code brittle.

Instead consider aspectj or annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Add `-Wp,-P` to your `gcc` invocation. `-Wp,` passes an argument to the preprocessor `cpp`, and `-P` inhibits generation of linemarkers when passed to `cpp`.